# Can you restrict access to parts of strapi admin?

Tags: strapi

Using Strapi to build an API. Love most of it, but it seems access to the admin interface is all or nothing; you can't hide the more advanced aspects of admin for users who should only be able to add/edit content...? Am I missing something? How is this done?

Answer (score 5):

This is the current top-voted feature request at Strapi. You can vote for it at: https://strapi.io/vote.

> **Admin - Permissions**
>
> Restrict admin panel sections access depending on users roles.

Comment: it's a [planned feature](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/tabs/3-planned)

Comment: It's [in progress](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/8-users-roles-permissions-ce-ee)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can change some things, since there is an `/admin` folder inside of `/node_modules` that you can overwrite, [as the documentation says here](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/admin-panel/customization.html#development-mode), you can overwrite some logic for specific users and specific cases, that's not the best way to do it, but it's what we have for now.

**Example**: In my project I don't want any user to access the Content-Types Builder on production, at the end, I decided to hide the entire Plugins section on production environment.

So firstly I copied the entire /admin folder inside of my project, that way it'd be simple to find/edit any component.

Secondly I searched were the sections where rendered, and I found this file:

`/my-project/admin/src/components/LeftMenuLinkSection/index.js`

And I added this inside of the component:

```js
const LeftMenuLinksSection = ({ section,
  ....
  // before the return
  if ( section === 'plugins' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') return null;;
```

And it worked, on production I don't have the plugins section on admin left menu (image 1):

It depends what you want to do, that could be possible, so it's not *"all or nothing"*, it's more like *all or almost nothing*.

[image: left admin menu on production]